# Recursive Algorithm to generate all permutations of length k of a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I want to create a recursive algorithm that will generate all permutations
of a specified length of a list of integers with some length `n`.

Following is my idea:

For every element in the list, I can remove it, then ask my recursive function to return to me all permutations of length `k-1`, and then to each of those permutations I will add the removed number. Then repeat this process for all numbers in the list.

The base cases are when the list is empty or contains only one element.
In these cases I just return the list. That is, as long as k is less than or equal to the length of the list (ex. if `k` is `3`, but `l = [1,2]`, I can't produce any permutations of length `k`).

This is what I've written:

```
def permutations(l, k):
w = len(l)
if (k <= w): # list is bigger than the length each permutations
    if (w <= 1):
        return list(l)
    else:
        result = []
        for element in l:
            listSmaller = l[:element] + l[element+1:]
            for perm in permutations(listSmaller, k-1):
                result.append([perm] + element)
        return result      
else: # list is not bigger than the length of the permutations, impossible.
    print("k cannot exceed length of list")
```

I keep getting `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

How should I modify this?

Comment: if you are trying to make it from scratch this wont help, but have you looked at the python `itertools` module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Could you please provide the parameters to `permutations` which are resulting in the reported error? Thanks!

Comment: When you use `for element in l:`, the `element` is no more an index starting from 0 but the individual elements of the list `l`, one at a time. Now while accessing the elements of the list `l` you can't use, `l[:element]` or `l[element+1:]`. You need an index which you can get using enumerate as `for i, element in enumerate(l):` and then you can use `l[:i] + l[i+1:]`

Comment: I've been testing with permutations([1,2,3,4], 3)

Comment: Also, perm is a list, so you shouldn’t wrap it with a [ ]. Element is an int so you should wrap it with a [ ] (in the line where you append to result)

Comment: Answering my own question: an add of the line `permutations([1,2], 2)` to the end of the above code results in the reported error.

Answer (score 3):

```
# code takes list lst and int n denoting length of permutation
# returns all permutations of length n over items in lst  
def Perm(lst,n):
    # if length of permutation is negative or 0, return empty
    if n<=0:
        return [[]]
    # else take empty list l 
    l=[]
    # loop over whole lst
    for i in range(0,len(lst)): 
        m=lst[i] # current element of lst (ith) 
        remLst=lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]  # remaining list i.e. all elements except ith
        # recursive call to Perm with remaining list and decremented length 
        for p in Perm(remLst,n-1): 
            # append current element + all sublists p generated through recursion as an item in list l
            l.append([m]+p) 
    return l

# some examples 
# all permutations of length 2 over characters A,B,C
print(Perm(['A','B','C'],2))
# output: [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'A'], ['B', 'C'], ['C', 'A'], ['C', 'B']]

# all permutations of length 2 over characters 1,2,3,4
print(Perm([1,2,3,4],2))
# output: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

**First**: `[perm] + element` Here you are adding a list to an integer.

**Second**: `listSmaller = l[:element] + l[element+1:]` Here you need an index to access the elements of the list. You are currently using the elements as an index and will therefore get an `IndexError` because when `element=4`, `element+1` will be `5` but you do not have `l[4+1:]`.

---

Your code works when I do the following changes in your code. I am only showing the modified lines. I am not sure if the output is as expected. You can try it and let me know.

```
for i, element in enumerate(l):
    listSmaller = l[:i] + l[i+1:]

    for perm in permutations(listSmaller, k-1):
        result.append([perm] + [element])
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, when using

```
for a in b:
```

'a' is not actually a number which can be used as an index, but is instead a pointer to an actual element in list 'b'. Put another way, if I had the following list

```
b = ["Bob", "Jim", "Jane"]
```

Then on the first iteration 'a' would be equal to "Bob", and not 0.

When you want to generate index numbers instead of pointers to elements, you can use:

```
for a in range(0, len(b)):
```

instead. Using this, your code should then work.

e.g.

```
for element in range(0, len(l)):
    listSmaller = l[:element] + l[element+1:]
    for perm in permutations(listSmaller, k-1):
        result.append([perm] + element)
return result
```