# How to get all permutations of a list taken k things at at a time using a user defined recursive function(Python)

Tags: python, list, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I'd like to make a recursive algorithm generating all permutations of a list of integers taken k things at a time.

To be specific, what I want to do is create a **recursive** function `Perm(list, k)` from scratch returning a output satisfying the following condition.

```
from itertools import permutations
li = [1,2,3,4]
set(permutations(li, 2)) == set(Perm(li, 2))
```

I tried it by referring to the Shailaja's codes (`Perm(lst,n)`) from this link: [Recursive Algorithm to generate all permutations of length k of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356091/recursive-algorithm-to-generate-all-permutations-of-length-k-of-a-list-in-python)

Since the function returns a nested list, I've tried to convert the nested list to a set of tuples. However, I was unable to find any solutions because the function is a recursive algorithm. Could anyone help me out to change the `Perm` function to get the following format of outputs? Thanks a lot.

```
# the output of set(Perm(li, 2)) 
{(1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (3, 4),
 (4, 1),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 3)}
```

Comment: Can `li` contain duplicates?

Comment: `[list(i) for i in permutations(li, 2)] == Perm(li, 2)`?

Comment: @CristiFati umm here I only want to change the `Perm` function itself.

Comment: I didn't change anything else. Try printing the equality test members, and also note that sets are unordered.

Comment: @CristiFati I got what you mean but here I was required not to change the `set(permutations(li, 2)) == set(Perm(li, 2))` equation. So the output format of the `Perm` function should be changed.

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry it doesn't allow duplicates

Comment: Are you looking for a new version of `Perm` (which is what @CristiFati gave you), or a way to flatten what you are currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the function returns a nested list, I've tried to convert the nested list to a set of tuples.

Yes, that is indeed what is needed. So `Perm` should yield tuples.

Here is a possible recursive implementation for `Perm`:

```
def Perm(lst, size):
    if size <= 0:
        yield ()   # empty tuple
    else:
        for i, val in enumerate(lst):
            for p in Perm(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:], size-1):
                yield (val, *p)
```

This passes the test given in the question.